# entity framework manual migrations ConnectionStringName overridden by DBContext base

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dbcontext, asp.net-mvc-areas

I'm implementing a Web Application based on ASP MVC 5 and Entity Framework 6. The solution is organized with Areas (only one by now...) and each Area has it's own DBContext.
See [Picture o the solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrPzC.png).

In the DBContext I defined a connection string name assigned to the Context at Run-time since it depends on a logon variable.

```
using System.Web;
using RMC.Areas.TimeSheet.Controllers;

namespace RMC.Areas.TimeSheet.DAL
{
    public class timeSheetContext : DbContext
    {
        public timeSheetContext()
            : base("name=DBConn_Data." + RMC.Controllers.BaseController.applicationName + ".FLAT")
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<timeSheetContext, RMC.Areas.TimeSheet.Migrations.Configuration>(true));
        }


        public DbSet<ts_activityProfile> activityProfile { get; set; }                  // Profilo delle attività
        public DbSet<ts_activityProfile_ML> activityProfile_ML { get; set; }            // Profilo delle attività
        public DbSet<ts_activity> activity { get; set; }                                // Attività
etc...
```

When I try to add a migration or to update the database from the Console, even if I specify the connection string explicitly (and the connection string exists in the main web.config!), the Migration tool tries to read it from the DBContext:base...where the run-time parameter is not defined.

i.e. Command

```
Add-MigrationMig000 -StartUpProjectName "RMC" -ProjectName "RMC" -ConfigurationTypeName "RMC.Areas.TimeSheet.Migrations.Configuration" -ConnectionStringName "DBConn_Data.re.FLAT" -Verbose
```

The error I get is:

```
No connection string named 'DBConn_Data..FLAT' could be found in the application config file.
```

It seems that it is ignoring the -ConnectionStringName passed. The only way I made it to work was commenting the :base(...) defined.

Shouldn't the -ConnectionStringName override the :base() ?
How can I make it work ?

Thanks

**EDIT**
Here is the BaseController

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

using System.Threading;
using RMC.Helpers;
using RMC.ViewModel;
using RMC.Models;
using RMC.ViewModel.navigation;


using System.Web.Configuration;


namespace RMC.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    public class BaseController : Controller
    {

        public static string applicationName = "";
        public static bool noValue = true;
        public static mLog oLog = null;
        public static string defaultCulture = "";       // Cultura di defautl del sistema impostata nel web.config

        protected override void Initialize(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext)
        {
            base.Initialize(requestContext);

            /* 20/02/2014
             Inizializzo la variabile statica che contiene l'application name.
             Viene utilizzata dal DBContext per trovare la connectionString corretta.
             */
            applicationName = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Items["ApplicationName"].ToString();
etc...
```

**EDIT2**
What's funny is that if I pass in the command a wrong connection string name it complains that the connection doesn't exist !
Wrong command

```
Update-Database -ConnectionStringName DBConn_Data.reXXX.FLAT -StartUpProjectName RMC -ProjectName RMC -ConfigurationTypeName RMC.Areas.TimeSheet.Migrations.Configuration -Verbose
```

Error message

```
No connection string named 'DBConn_Data.reXXX.FLAT' could be found in the application config file.
```

Comment: Could you please provide code of your `RMC.Controllers.BaseController` ?

Comment: This is just  a guess, but if EF migrations needs to instantiate your DbContext and pass the connection string, it can't do it with your current configuration. Can you try adding a constructor which accepts the connection string name and passes it to the base constructor?

Comment: See edit: I added the beginning of the Controller

Comment: Thanks Francesc Castells, tryed adding the constructor you suggest, but the migration tool is still looking for the connection string defined in the :base of the parameterless constructor. Doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Fo some unknown reason your `RMC.Controllers.BaseController.applicationName` variable is empty. That's why you've got the exception message.

My suggestion for you, try to move this variable in some Static field, for example:

```
public static class Settings {
    public static string AppName = "MyApp";
}
```

And that you could use it in your Context:

```
public timeSheetContext()
        : base("name=DBConn_Data." + Settings.AppName + ".FLAT")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<timeSheetContext, RMC.Areas.TimeSheet.Migrations.Configuration>(true));
    }
```

Comment: Hi, the RMC.Controllers.BaseController.applicationName is supposed to be empty at this stage, since it is fulfilled only at runtime. Since the application is multi DB (same structure, many different DB) it gets initialized at user log in. My point is to be able to apply manual migrations providing connection string names one by one from the console.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I ended up with a solution I DO NOT LIKE...but works.
I modified the DBContext in this way

```
namespace RMC.Areas.TimeSheet.DAL
{
    public class timeSheetContext : DbContext
    {
        /* Used from Package Manager Console during manual Migrations */
        public timeSheetContext()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<timeSheetContext, RMC.Areas.TimeSheet.Migrations.Configuration>(true));
        }

        /* Used by App. Must pass the application name every time !*/
        public timeSheetContext(string applicationName)
            : base("name=DBConn_Data." + applicationName + ".FLAT")
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<timeSheetContext, RMC.Areas.TimeSheet.Migrations.Configuration>(true));
        }
```

So when I run manual migration the first constructor gets used (passing the -ConnectionStringName parameter...) and in the application teh second one gets used, but I  have to pass the applicationName every time.

If anybody has a better solution please post !